# Deploying a Grails web app that requires HTTPS on Cloud Foundry

Tags: grails, cloud-foundry

I have deployed a very simple Grails test app on Cloud Foundry which uses spring-security for the login page.

I want to require HTTPS access for this login page so that passwords are not sent in clear text.

First thing I did was to browse to my test app using HTTPS which worked fine, so that confirmed that Cloud Foundry can service HTTPS requests for my app.

Next I added the following to Config.groovy to require HTTPS access to my pages:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.auth.forceHttps = true

grails.plugins.springsecurity.secureChannel.definition = [
        '/': 'REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL'
]
```

Now when I try to deploy using `grails cf-update` it hangs when `Trying to start application...`

If if I remove the requirement for HTTPS it succeeds.

I'm guessing that maybe there is a problem with the check for whether the application has started. Is this using a HTTP url which is then getting redirected to HTTPS as I cannot see any problems in the logs?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that there currently is an issue with CloudFoundry + Spring Security where `HttpServletRequest.isSecure()` does not return the correct value when using https. This trumps Spring Security in doing an infinite redirect loop when requiring a secure channel.

I witnessed that on a plain Spring project, but this may be what your grails project is suffering from. One workaround at the moment would be to wrap your HttpServletRequests so that `isSecure()` looks at the scheme to decide what to return.

If you try your secured URL in a browser, what do you get (assuming the app has actually started, although the grails plugin tells otherwise)

Comment: I tried the secured URL in the browser during the hang and unfortunately do not get a response which may invalidate my original theory.

Comment: ebottard is right. if you try "grails cf-log", you will find the app was actaully started. and when you hit the url, something like "hitting_url has resulted in too many redirects". need to figure out what is wrong within cf.

Comment: Yep, agree, can see the "too many redirect message now". If I go directly to the HTTPS version of the login url it works fine. Should I raise this as a bug?

Comment: Yes, you can raise a ticket at http://support.cloudfoundry.com. log in with your cloudfoundry credential. it has sso enabled with cf.com.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that [cloudfoundry terminates HTTPS at the loadbalancer](http://support.cloudfoundry.com/entries/20153602-is-it-possible-to-visit-my-application-via-ssl-https). And there is no way to get HTTPS all the way to your app, so 'REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL' will not work on cloudfoundry.

If you want a gross hack to try to check that HTTPS was used between the user and the loadbalancer you can look at the headers in a filter. Eg.

```
    sslHeaderRequireFilter(controller:'*', action:'*') {
        before = {
            def headerNames = request.headerNames.collect{ it }             
            if(! headerNames.contains('sslclientcertstatus') ){
                render "Only available on https"
                return false    
            }                   
        }
    }
```

Comment: The problem isn't that CF terminates at the router. The problem is that CF doesn't included the x-forwarded-proto header for HTTP calls as it should. This is needed for the plugin to operate properly.